# Could not resolve artifact

Tags: maven, jsp, heroku, jdbc

I'm trying to host a java-web application in Heroku. First, i converted my application in a maven project, then i added the dependencies, but when i try to deploy the app, heroku say that "The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.oracle.jdbc:ojdbc8:jar:12.2.0.1, javax.sql:jdbc-stdext:jar:2.0: Could not find artifact com.oracle.jdbc:ojdbc8:jar:12.2.0.1 in central "
I already tried to add dependency manually in pom.xml, but the error still doesn't resolve.

[pom.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbsOH.jpg)

[Heroku log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVpTp.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It cannot find the com.oracle.jdbc dependency (probably an old packaging, it has been relocated), try instead

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
  <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
  <version>12.2.0.1</version>
```

You can navigate/check the Oracle dependencies at Maven Central Repository (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/oracle)